# c# xamarin use value from other void

Tags: c#, visual-studio, variables, xamarin, spinner

I have a void like this:

```
public void AssignmentsTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Set view to Assignments
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Assignments);

    //Fill ActionSpinner
    Spinner ActionSpinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.ActionSpinner);
    ActionSpinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(ActionSpinner_ItemSelected);
    var ActionSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(this, Resource.Array.action_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
 ActionSpinnerAdapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
    ActionSpinner.Adapter = ActionSpinnerAdapter;

    AssignmentListData = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ListviewAssignments);
}
```

And a this void after:

```
private void ActionSpinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
    string toast = string.Format("Selected coin is {0}", spinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position));
    Toast.MakeText(this, toast, ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

Now I want in the first void the value of the spinner, so I used this:

```
var SelectedSpinnerAction = ActionSpinner.GetItemAtPosition(e.Position);
```

But that gives an error on the word Position... What can I do???

EDIT: This is the error
"'EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Position' and no extension method 'Position' accepting a first argument of type 'EventArgs' could not be found."

Comment: Which is the error message ?

Comment: "e" means completely different things in those two different contexts.  In the first, it contains arguments related to the tab click, so it will NOT tell you the position of the spinner.  Since the spinner is not even initialized at this point, it's fair to assume that it's position is 0.

Comment: yeah I understand that, but is there a way to get the value in that void?

Comment: I added the error to my question below!

Comment: as I said before, you just created the spinner and the user has not interacted with it yet, so you can probably assume that it's position is 0.

Comment: Yeah, but the spinner got multiple values, so mulitple posistions. I want to share the specific posistion!

Comment: Someone please HELP!!!